# linq union group by undefined

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I am calling the following function from a web service but can't get the object defined.

```
Dim x = (From a In _db.report _
     Select ep = a.CurrentReport, CuCy = a.Current_Cycle) _
   .Union _
     (From b In _db.Counts _
       Group b By b.Year, b.Report Into k() _ <--------(this is undefined)
      Select ep = b.Report, CucY = b.Year).ToList().Take(10)
```

Is this the correct way to do a group by in a union query?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm not completely sure about this, but I think the parentheses after `k` are not needed: `Group By [...] Into k Select [...]`

Comment: They are automatically added. I have deleted them but it adds them back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grouping syntax in VB is slightly different than C#. The Group By requires you to state `Into Group` rather than aliasing the new structure. See if the following works for you:

```
Dim x = (From a In _db.report _
     Select ep = a.CurrentReport, CuCy = a.Current_Cycle) _
   .Union _
     (From b In _db.Counts _
       Group By b.Year, b.Report Into Group _ <--------(this is undefined)
      Select ep = Key.Report, Key.Year).ToList().Take(10)
```

Since you don't appear to be aggregating in the second query, you might be able to just do a distinct instead:

```
From b in _db.Counts
Select b.Report, B.Year
Distinct
```